# Deploying Ruby on Rails app to Heroku rejected saying default language pack not detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, deployment

Here is the terminal result: So the error with language detention problem is with the command "$ git push heroku master"

```
tom100j:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 133, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (118/118), done.
Writing objects: 100% (133/133), 24.39 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 133 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:      HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect     
             the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to murmuring-stream-98615.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-stream-98615.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-stream-98615.git'
tom100j:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $
```

I have tried to go through what the problem is and even change the version of the ruby in the app. The gemfile is below.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.3.0"

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end



gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test doconsole
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby, :ruby]

group :production do
   gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end
```

Anybody hot solution for this?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support

Comment: Any chance that you have `gemfile` with lowercase letter? Or maybe you forgot to add it to repository? If you added official ruby buildpack it should only check for `Gemfile`.

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak the _gemfile_ is like `Gemfile` and it is already added to repo.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku couldn't detect the buildpack your application needs

> Buildpacks are responsible for transforming deployed code into a slug, which can then be executed on a dyno.

First you should check if there's any buildpack set for the app by running, if theres none you should see the following message

```
$ heroku buildpacks
APP_NAME has no Buildpack URL set.
```

If there's a buildpack already selected you could remove it by issueing

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
```

Then manually set the buildpack for the application by running

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```

Try to push the app again. If it continues to fail you should check 
that the Gemfile.lock file contains a railties gem, and the gem version is greater than or equal to 5.0.0.beta, and less than 6.0.0. As suggested by [Heroku Ruby Support for Rails 5.x applications](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rails-5-x-applications)

Comment: Actually I have tried all that. clearing the buildpack and setting it to ruby exactly in steps you mentioned. In that case, the error slightly changes to *Failed to detect app matching no buildpack* and references [detection-failure](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure) According to the documentation, as long as the gemfile is in root, it should be able to detect.
Railties gem is **railties (5.0.2)**